# No interpreta HTML que hay dentro de los campos de la tabla

Tags: php, symfony

Primero disculpar si el título no hace referencia muy bien a la duda que tengo. No sabría como interpretarlo mejor.

Estoy aprendiendo Symfony y me encuentro con los formularios y como traer los datos de la BBDD. Por el momento me lo trae todo bien, pero en los campos de la BBDD si se encuentra código html, este al traerlo a la vista no se muestra, es decir.. no aparecen saltos de linea, negritas, o cualquier cosa que sea con el uso de etiquetas. Directamente suelta todo el texto uno detrás de otro en linea.

El campo en la tabla de la BBDD se encuentra como **longtext** y ahora os pongo todo el código para ver si podéis orientarme en donde me estoy equivocando.

He creado un servicio con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Entity\Posts;

class ListPosts
{
    public $doctrine; 

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine){
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function listPosts(){
        $entityManager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $posts = $entityManager->getRepository(Posts::class)->findAll();
        return $posts;
    }

    public function listPostById($id){
        $entityManager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $posts = $entityManager->getRepository(Posts::class)->find($id);
        return $posts;
    }

}
```

El controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Posts;
use App\Form\PostType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Service\ListPosts;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PostController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/post', name: 'app_post')]
    public function index(ListPosts $list, ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'PostController',
            'list' => $list->listPosts()
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/post/{id}', name: 'app_post_id')]
    public function indexId(ListPosts $post, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, int $id): Response
    {
        return $this->render('post/indexById.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'PostController',
            'post' => $post->listPostById($id)
        ]);
    }

}
```

Este es el formulario de symfony:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Posts;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('date', DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Posts::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Y esta es la vista:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello PostController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container example-wrapper">
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <div class="img-featured">
        <img class="img-fluid mt-5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1300x600" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5 mb-5">{{ post.content }}</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Como he dicho el servicio me funciona, me trae y me muestra el campo de la tabla, pero en caso de que esta alguna etiqueta html como un salto de liena, negrita, encabezados, etc... se muestra la etiqueta en vez de interpretarla. Esto me es esencial si quiero mostrar por ejemplo el contenido de un post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto, Twig va a escapar el contenido antes de mostrarlo en la página.

Para evitarlo es necesario usar el filtro raw.
En tu caso sería algo así:

```
{{ post.content | raw }}
```

Puedes ver la documentación en este enlace:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html